# What is the official name for this concept?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, terminology, function-and-relation-composition

I've been playing with abstract functions and infinite sets and have come up with the concept of a "requisite function". Since the concept is relatively simple, if the concept is not flawed, then someone must have come up with this concept before and named it. The question is, what is the official name for this concept?

$A$ and $B$ are infinite sets.
$f: A \to| B$ is a partial function such that **some** elements of $A$ are mapped to **some** elements of $B$. 

Set $A'$ is the restricted subset of $A$ such that **every** element of $A'$ is mapped to **some** element of $B$.

 A requisite function $f_r: A \to A'$ maps **every** element of $A$ to **every** element of $A'$. If an element of $A$ is already in $A'$, $f_r$ does **not** necessarily map the given element to itself.

 Example 1: 

Sets $A$ and $B$ are identical sets of all natural numbers. $f(x)=\frac x2=y$ such that $x \in A$ and $y \in B$. Therefore, $x$ must be divisible by $2$. Therefore, $A'$ is the set of all natural numbers that are divisible by $2$. Therefore, $f_r(x)=2x$. 

This concept also extends to function powers: if $f^2(x)=\frac x {2^2}$ such that $x \in A$ and $y \in B$, then $x$ must be divisible by $2^2$. Therefore, the requisite function of $f^2(x)$ is $f^2_r(x)=2^2x$. 

In general, if $f^n(x)=\frac x {2^n}$ then $f_r$ of $f^n(x)$ is $f^n_r(x)=2^nx$.

Example 2:

Sets $A$ and $B$ are identical sets of all natural numbers. $f(x)=x+1$ such that $x \in A$ and $y \in B$. Every element of $A$ is already mapped to some element of $B$, therefore $A=A'$, therefore $f_r(x)$ is just an identity function.

Comment: Do you mean the _range_ of the function? (As contrasted with the _codomain_.)

Comment: There are partial functions, which are relations $f: A \to B$ such that not all elements of $a$ are mapped, and there exists a subset $A' \subseteq A$ for which $f |_{A'}$ is a function. Don't know about these "requisite functions", though.

Comment: @Patrick Stevens Range of the function would be a subset of B, since B is the codomain. I mean a function that maps A to something like 'inverse range'.

Comment: Sounds like you are just looking for a surjective (a.k.a. onto) function from an infinite set $A$ to a subset $A'$.

Comment: Can't you just pick an arbitrary element $a\in A'$ and define $f(x) = x$ if $x\in A'$ and $a$ otherwise? That satisfies your stated conditions.

Comment: @Rahul Yes, I'm looking for a surjective function from $A$ fo $A'$. Yes, the function can link an element from $A'$ to itself, but it doesn't have to.

Comment: This particular setup is specialized enough that there probably isn't a name for it, but also, I'm not sure that the idea itself is really a useful one in most contexts. For example, if I had a function $f$ on {0,1,2} then I could compose the "requisite function" "take the residue modulo 3" to extend $f$ to the integers, but why not just define $f$ on integers modulo 3? Basically, the requisite functions seem to just be a way to implicitly define the equivalence relation you need, but I think it's more common to define the equivalence relation explicitly.